# Url Replacement in React App when deployed on K8s

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, create-react-app, haproxy

We have a CRA (Create React App) application that we need to deploy to different environments. We're using Kubernetes to spawn these environments so we will have many of them, the number is not fixed.

The problem is that those environments must be under the same domain name and must have the same path structure. (this is a business requirement and we cannot influence it).

Example of environments:

```
https://www.example.com/app-env01/react_application/
https://www.example.com/app-env02/react_application/
https://www.example.com/app-env03/react_application/
```

We have the app working by doing this:

- Pass the dynamic part (`app-env-bar`) as an environment variable
- In the `entrypoint.sh` add the passed argument to the `base href` property
- Set a variable like `window.env.PART_URL` to be used in the app

Our deployment artifact is a Docker image, which has `PM2` serving previously built React static files.

This app is hosted through `HaProxy` and the url is stripped of the dynamic part (eg `app-env01`) during ingress. So when the browser hits `https://www.example.com/app-env01/react_application/` HaProxy gets `/react_application`

Now the **problem** we are facing is that as soon as the url gets hit and the app loads the url is replaced in the browser to be without the dynamic part (eg `app-env01`).

For eg:

```
On hitting - https://www.example.com/app-env01/react_application/

this url in the browser gets replaced by - https://www.example.com/react_application/
```

Now the app being SPA keeps working fine but as soon as the user refreshes the page this url being incorrect gives an error.

Please Help!

Comment: Please provide more information about your current setup - which Kubernetes version are you using, which solution did you use to setup a cluster (kubeadm or some cloud provider solution etc.). And please provide your Ingress deployment in order to understand what is set in your Paths